# Reactjs deployement on Heroku App crashed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to deploy React app on Heroku. I see on log file it's build is fine. While running it on browser, it says, "Starting the development server...". But suddenly it gives error.

*Process exited with status 0.*

and

*State changed from starting to crashed.*

I have searched a lot in google and found many solutions to this specific error but none of them works for me.

Here is my package.json file:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.1.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.4"
},
```

scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

I am using yarn not npm.

This is what it says when I click on view button after deployement:

```
2020-05-21T23:10:18.672143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testmystorespeed.herokuapp.com request_id=83e14391-8f4a-442b-8ee6-6904d095e258 fwd="39.42.33.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

and

```
2020-05-21T23:10:20.773731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testmystorespeed.herokuapp.com request_id=e8a2be81-7d60-44f4-9746-f2e2f3789e79 fwd="39.42.33.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

N.B. Maybe someone said it is a duplicate question but I have tried almost everything that I found here in StackOverflow and others forums also.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is mainly for dynamic apps. So you may try netlify or even github pages to deploy your static react app.

This is how my package.json for the Pokedex app look for deploying on github pages.
https://github.com/AshutoshAgrawal2004/Pokedex

```
{
"name": "pokedex",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"homepage": "https://ashutoshagrawal2004.github.io/Pokedex",
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
```

}

Here's a tutorial https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-deploy-your-react-application-to-github-pages-in-less-than-5-minutes-8c5f665a2d2a

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with Heroku using node.js buildpack by default preventing create-react-app from deploying.